# Delete from Redis Sorted Set based on JSON Property

Tags: json, redis, sortedset

I have a large number of items stored in a Redis Sorted Set (of the order 100,000) that fairly frequently get updated. These items are objects encoded as JSON strings, and the rank for sorting in the set is derived (on insert, by my code) from a date/time property on the object.

Each item in the set has an Id property (which is a Guid encoded as a string) which uniquely identifies the item within the system.

When these items are updated, I need to either update the item within the sorted set, or delete and reinsert the item. The problem I have is how to find that item to perform the operation.

What I'm currently doing is loading the entire contents of the sorted set into memory, operating on that collection in my code and then writing the complete collection back to Redis. Whilst this works, it's not particularly efficient and won't scale well if the lists start to grow very large.

Would anybody have any suggestions as to how to do this in a more efficient manner? The only unique identifier I have for the items is the Id property as encoded in the item.

Many Thanks,

Richard.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Probably, your case is just a bad design choice.

You shouldn't store JSON strings in sorted sets: you need to store identifiers, and the whole JSON serialized objects should be stored in a *hash*.

This way, when you need to update an object, you update the whole hash key using `hset` and you can locate the whole object by  its unique identifier.

In the other hand, any key in the hash must be present in your sorted set. When you add an object to the sorted set, you're adding its unique identifier.

When you need to list your objects in a particular order, you do the following operations:

1. You get a page of identifiers from the sorted set (for example, using `zrange`).
2. You get all objects from the page giving their identifiers to a `hmget` command.

Comment: The use of a Hash for storing the ID->JSON data is recommended but not mandatory as you could use a String to store each ID's JSON under its own key. That said, the Hash is preferable in terms of RAM because of Redis' per key overhead.

Comment: @ItamarHaber Hey, how's going? ;) Yes, I was using the string key approach until I realized that hases are better not only because of memory optimizations, but also because who wants a global key space poluted with milions of keys when you can organize them in subkeys

Comment: Hola:) As a fellow OCD-wannabe I get that, but for all practical reasons (RAM optimization excluded) subkeys aren't really helpful unless you're scanning the keyspace - a bad idea most of the times - or perform "batch" operations on subkeys (e.g. mass delete). OTOH, they add another O(logn) for fetching the value...

Comment: @ItamarHaber Well, you're right... That's my case, where I'm using hashes to store serialized objects by some "key property", and then I need to get them by some criteria. This is why I tend to use the hash-sorted set (or just a set, list, or whatever) approach.

Comment: You're absolutely correct that it was a bad design choice - I come from the SQL world, and it was the first thing I wrote with Redis. I wouldn't do it the same way again, and I think the time has come to reimplement in the manner @MatíasFidemraizer suggests.

Comment: @RichardComish Well, you'll see that once you get used with working with simple data structures, SQL will feel a mess for you ;P

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer I very much suspect you're right!